# What is wrong with this description list?

Tags: math-mode, description

The below snippet is supposed to show a list of items and some associated values which I've stored as new commands. Unfortunately, what happens instead is a mess. I've included everything I think might be relevant, though I'm not sure how to actually display the resulting garble. Maybe it's something to do with using math mode for subscripts?

What I get is nothing like what I was expecting:
[image]

I want the descriptions to be inline with the \paragraph{} block. I'm not sure why R1 and the garble of R1 and R2 are like they are, or why the values appear to have situated themselves as a jumble after R1 in "Actual Component Values."

I'm a complete beginner to LaTeX and I don't even know where to begin ... what's happening here and how do I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}   %https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics
\usepackage{siunitx} % Provides the \SI{}{} and \si{} command for typesetting SI units
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for the inclusion of images
\usepackage{cite}
.
.
.
\newcommand{\cOneTrue}{.875 nF}
\newcommand{\rOneCalc}{18.189 k\Omega}
\newcommand{\rOneTrue}{6.187 k\Omega}
\newcommand{\rTwoTrue}{12.079 k\Omega}
\newcommand{\rNetTrue}{18.266 k\Omega}
.
.
.
\subsection{Low Pass Filter}
\paragraph{Calculated Necessary Resistance:}
    \begin{description}
        \item[\(R_1\)]      \rOneCalc
    \end{description}
\paragraph{Actual Component Values: }
    \begin{description}
        \item[\(C_1\)]      \cOneTrue
        \item[\(R_1\)]      \rOneTrue
        \item[\(R_2\)]      \rTwoTrue
        \item[\(R_{net}\)]  \rNetTrue
    \end{description}
```

Comment: Further to @Gonzalo's answer, I can only reproduce the result you show by putting TeX into nonstop mode, so that it ploughs on through errors. Don't do this!

Comment: I'm using sharelatex ... I'm not sure how to turn nonstop mode off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you process your document (after suitable completion) you get an eeror message:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.18         \item[\(R_1\)]      \rOneCalc
```

which gives you a hint about the problem. With your current definitions, you need math-mode for your `\cOneCalc`, `\rOneTrue`,... commands (and probably will need to add spaces, and fix the font for the "k" also). However, the best thing to do here is to use `siunitx`, which you are already loading, to get the proper spacing and fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}   %https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics
\usepackage{siunitx} % Provides the \SI{}{} and \si{} command for typesetting SI units
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for the inclusion of images
\usepackage{cite}

\newcommand{\cOneTrue}{\SI{.875}{\nano\farad}}
\newcommand{\rOneCalc}{\SI{18.189}{\kilo\ohm}}
\newcommand{\rOneTrue}{\SI{6.187}{\kilo\ohm}}
\newcommand{\rTwoTrue}{\SI{12.079}{\kilo\ohm}}
\newcommand{\rNetTrue}{\SI{18.266}{\kilo\ohm}}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Low Pass Filter}
\paragraph{Calculated Necessary Resistance:}
\begin{description}
\item[\(R_1\)] \rOneCalc
\end{description}

\paragraph{Actual Component Values: }
\begin{description}
\item[\(C_1\)] \cOneTrue
\item[\(R_1\)] \rOneTrue
\item[\(R_2\)] \rTwoTrue
\item[\(R_{\text{net}}\)] \rNetTrue
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, instead of defining a dedicated command for each specific value

```
\newcommand{\rOneCalc}{\SI{18.189}{\kilo\ohm}}
\newcommand{\rOneTrue}{\SI{6.187}{\kilo\ohm}}
\newcommand{\rTwoTrue}{\SI{12.079}{\kilo\ohm}}
\newcommand{\rNetTrue}{\SI{18.266}{\kilo\ohm}}
```

perhaps you would be better off (I'm not sure and it depends on the actual document needs) defining a command, such as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\MyKO}[1]{\SI{#1}{\kilo\ohm}}

\begin{document}

\MyKO{18.189}
\MyKO{6.187}
\MyKO{12.079}
\MyKO{18.266}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Because of the \Omega?

Comment: @DanielB. Yes, because of the `\Omega`.  Alternately, you could place delimiters around the `\Omega` directly in the definitions, and then not need them in the `\item`s.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\kilo\ohm` or `\kohm`?

Comment: @egreg Yes, I'm on it.

Comment: @DanielB. Yes, with your current definitions you'll need math-mode for the `\Omega`; however, since you are loading `siunitx`, the best approach here use its features for your units (see code at the bottom of my answer).

Comment: I suggest `\nano\farad`